# Running automated Flutter test with CI

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, automated-tests, teamcity

#### I want to:

Run tests to when code is checked in to a Flutter project.

#### Given:

I have access to an enterprise instance of GitHub and TeamCity using a Linux a build agent with the [flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) installed.

#### Problem:

When I run `flutter test` I get the error –

```sh
$ flutter test
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.                       

Because your_friend_ken depends on webview_flutter any which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.11.9 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in e3c3b5eae44b8865...                        
pub get failed (1)
```

When I run `flutter doctor` –

```sh
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v0.0.0-unknown, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

#### Questions:

Is there a better to automate tests on for Flutter projects?

Should/How would I install Android Studio on a linux vm via command line?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: there is other way to automate tests in Flutter like using [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/), [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) or configuring your own Docker container but you still might want to be able to perform your test locally with `flutter test`.
You definitely should install Android Studio but I recommend instaling it through the website instead of command line (which might change depend on your distribution)